# segue.identifier = nil in second view

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have IOS Swift program, using Storyboards with NavigationController.
There are two Views, lets call them mainView, secondView.

From the mainView I have BarButtonItem to go to secondView. When pressing that button, it triggers prepareForSegue function in the mainView with segue.identifier = "secondView"

When I have opend e.g. the secondView, I have two BarButtonItems for Cancel and Save.  When pressing either of them the prepareForSegue function in that view is triggered, but now the segue.identifier = nil.

I would have expected to have the segue.identifier = "cancel" or "save" depended on the button pressed in that view.

Am I misunderstanding the segue functionality? Can anyone try to enlight me about this, as this looks like a very important and useful part of storyboards and navigation - but somehow I am not getting it right.

Comment: what did you do to trigger the segues? that is not the default behaviour of a button!

Comment: If you want to use a segue to go back to a previous view controller from your buttons, you need to use an unwind segue. Never go back to a previous controller with any other kind of segue, because they don't really "go back", they create a new instance of the destination view controller. If you don't want to use an unwind, then you can just pop or dismiss in code depending on whether the forward segue was a push or modal presentation.

Comment: @rdelmar "use an unwind segue", interesting.  Do you have any direction to point me into for more reading?

Comment: @luk2303 I have draged the BarButtonItems to the Exit and connect the segue.  So the segue is happening, but just on the mainView and not in the secondView. So I am just confused :)

Comment: Link to unwind segue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992040/xcode-swift-go-back-to-previous-viewcontroller-tableviewcontroller/29012193#29012193

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Garret, @rdelmar, @syed-tariq - thank you for pointing me into the right direction.

It turned out that Unwind Segue got me on track: [Xcode Swift Go back to previous viewController (TableViewController)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992040/xcode-swift-go-back-to-previous-viewcontroller-tableviewcontroller/29012193#29012193)

But I also found one error I was doing in my storyboard, as I had Navigation Controller on all views (yes, I know - stupid when you know better): [How do I segue values when my ViewController is embedded in an UINavigationController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29641325/how-do-i-segue-values-when-my-viewcontroller-is-embedded-in-an-uinavigationcontr)

The final puzzle was to learn about the [Protocols and Deligates](http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/01/swift-swift-using-segues-and-delegates-in-navigation-controllers-part-1-the-template/) to get this all to work.

Putting this together, then in short:

1. I created a protocol in my second view (above the class)

   ```
   protocol MyDelegate: class {
       func getMyList(sender: MySecondView) -> [NSManagedObject]  //returns a CoreData list
   }
   ```
2. Then I created a delegate variable in my second view

   ```
   weak var datasource: MyDelegate!
   ```
3. In my first view I implemented the protocol, which was just one simple function returning a list that I needed in my second view
4. In my first view I have prepareForSegue where I catch the correct segue.identifier and there I set the delegate by going through segue.destinationViewController, like this

   ```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
       // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
       // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
       if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {
           let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! MySecondView
           vc.delegate = self
       }
   }
   ```

and that was about it - now magically the flow is correct, segues happening, deligates passing correctly, and all good :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you created actions for the cancel and save buttons on your second view? 
Right click and drag from your storyboard to the view controller code and select action from the dropdown.

Then in the action method, perform your segue.

Comment: Yes, I have two BarButtonItems on my Navigation and I have draged it into my view to create an action outlet.  However that one is never triggered ... (which is maybe my real problem)

Comment: Ok, I have progress - after I removed the segue from the second view and only kept the action outlet, I got a hit! :-)
Now I only have to figure out how to make that buttonAction make me move back to the mainView after I have done the save.

Comment: self.performSegueWithIdentifier(

Comment: override func prepareForSegue(